# Setting Up My Server to Do DNS On OpenSuse 11.3

Tags: domain-name-system, bind, opensuse

I am attempting to use my server to be a DNS server. I am having trouble getting the domain setup. Here is what I have so far:

`/var/lib/named/master/andydaykin.com` :

```
$TTL 2d
@               IN SOA          andydaykin.com. root.andydaykin.com. (
                                2011011000      ; serial
                                0               ; refresh
                                0               ; retry
                                0               ; expiry
                                0 )             ; minimum

andydaykin.com. IN NS           ns1.andydaykin.com.
andydaykin.com. IN SOA          ns1.andydaykin.com. hostmaster.andydaykin.com. (
@.andydaykin.com.       IN NS           ns1.andydaykin.com.
ns1.andydaykin.com.     IN A            204.12.227.33
www.andydaykin.com.     IN A            204.12.227.33
```

`/etc/resolve.conf` :

```
search andydaykin.com
nameserver 204.12.227.33
```

`/etc/named.conf` :

```
options {
        # The directory statement defines the name server's working directory
        directory "/var/lib/named";

        dump-file "/var/log/named_dump.db";
        statistics-file "/var/log/named.stats";

        listen-on port 53 { 127.0.0.1; };

        listen-on-v6 { any; };

        notify no;

        disable-empty-zone "1.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.0.IP6.ARPA";
        include "/etc/named.d/forwarders.conf";
};


zone "." in {
        type hint;
        file "root.hint";
};

zone "localhost" in {
        type master;
        file "localhost.zone";
};

zone "0.0.127.in-addr.arpa" in {
        type master;
        file "127.0.0.zone";
};


# Include the meta include file generated by createNamedConfInclude.  This
# includes all files as configured in NAMED_CONF_INCLUDE_FILES from
# /etc/sysconfig/named

include "/etc/named.conf.include";
zone "andydaykin.com" in {
        file "master/andydaykin.com";
        type master;
        allow-transfer { any; };
};
logging {
        category default { log_syslog; };
        channel log_syslog { syslog; };
};
```

What I am doing wrong?

Answer (score 0):

I notice that you have '/etc/resolve.conf' - this is normally '/etc/resolv.conf'

- What happens to make you conclude that you are doing something wrong?